# Saber si el búfer de entrada stdin está vacío en C estándar

Tags: c, entrada, stdin, búfer

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera, sin salirse del estándar de C, de saber si el búfer de entrada `stdin` está vacío. El objetivo es limpiar correctamente dicho búfer ya que, al usar alguna de las siguientes dos opciones para ello:

```
char c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

o

```
scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");
```

en el caso de que el búfer de entrada estuviese vacío se quedaría pendiente esperando a recibir datos por teclado, siendo contraproducente porque el objetivo al limpiar el búfer de entrada es simplemente vaciarlo (evitando más adelante leer restos de datos introducidos anteriormente) de manera transparente, y no solicitar datos. En resumen, limpiar el búfer en el caso de tener contenido y, si está vacío, no hacer nada.

Proceso para limpiar: una vez sabido cuándo el búfer de entrada está o no vacío, simplemente se va leyendo cada carácter de la entrada hasta comprobar que esté limpio, momento en el cual se dejaría de leer para no quedarse pendiente de solicitar datos por teclado.

**Actualización**: Al hacer `scanf("%d", &n)` no hay ningún problema para saber si quedan datos en el búfer porque siempre quedan datos en el búfer si después del especificador `%d` no hay espacio en blanco. Si hubiese espacio en blanco `scanf("%d ", &n)` significaría que una vez introducido el número por teclado se limpia del búfer `stdin` el salto de línea posterior dejándolo vacío. Por lo tanto, en este caso no se sabría el estado del búfer de `stdin` una vez ejecutado el `scanf`, ya que estaría vacío o no dependiendo si el usuario mete uno o varios números separados por espacio.

Si después del identificador no hay espacio en blanco, significa que el salto de línea pulsado para introducir el dato queda en el búfer, habiendo siempre contenido en el búfer aun cuando sólo se introduce un número correctamente. Por lo tanto, se podría limpiar el búfer sin peligro a continuación.

Para el caso de leer cadenas de caracteres con `gets` o `getchar`, como sí se lee el salto de línea al introducir la cadena, entonces la manera de proceder es la expuesta en la solución de @eferion para saber manualmente si hay contenido en el búfer de `stdin` tras introducir los datos.

Comment: La función `fflush` sólo está definida su comportamiento en el estándar de C para búferes de salida. Para búfer de entrada como `stdin` no está definida, siendo bastante probable que no funcione.

Comment: La función `scanf()` considera como caracteres en blanco a los siguientes: espacio en blanco, tabulador o salto de línea. Si alguno de estos tres está dentro del argumento cadena formato hará que `scanf()` ignore cualquier tipo de carácter en blanco considerando a los tres tipos de manera indistina. En cambio, dentro de `[]` en un especificador, sí que considera caracteres distintos a tabulador, salto de línea o espacio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un detalle que has omitido, no se si deliberadamente o sin querer, es que normalmente el buffer se elimina después de una lectura sucia... es decir, cuando sabes que el buffer tiene datos considerados basura.

Si añades ese supuesto a tu ecuación el primer código que has añadido soluciona perfectamente tu problema:

```
char c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

El segundo sistema que presentas creo recordar que tiene como inconveniente que se atasca si el primer caracter del buffer de entrada es justamente un salto de línea... pero no tengo ahora mismo un entorno donde probarlo y confirmarlo.

Sacado de un comentario ¿Cómo actuar si el usuario excede el máximo permitido?

C es un lenguaje de bajo nivel con sus virtudes y sus problemas... pero este no debería ser uno de ellos:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 10
int main()
{
  char buffer[MAX+1] = {0};

  int i;
  for( i=0; i<MAX; i++ )
  {
    char c = getc(stdin);
    if( c == '\n' ) break;
    buffer[i] = c;
  }

  if( i == MAX ) // Limpiamos stdin solo si hemos llenado el buffer
  {
    char c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
  }

  printf("%s\n",buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Si, tienes razón. Pero por ejemplo si ejecutas: `scanf("%9s", cadena)` o `fgets(cadena, 10, stdin)` donde cadena es `char cadena[10]` (porque como `cadena` tiene un límite de 10 caracteres limitas la entrada para que como máximo lea ese tamaño en `cadena`), el usuario puede introducir menos o más de 10 caracteres. De manera que en la siguiente lectura no sabes si hay o no basura en el búfer.

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez Es que en esos casos no deberías hacer ese tipo de lecturas. Estas lecturas están reservadas para aquellas situaciones en las que puedes asumir que el ancho es ese... sin más.

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez Lo que se debería hacer en esos casos es leer en un buffer más grande (seguramente toda la línea) y después recuperar únicamente lo que te interesa o ir leyendo caracter a caracter hasta llegar al tope marcado (y lanzar una operación de limpieza posterior) o encontrarse un salto de línea... es lo que tiene trabajar con lenguajes de bajo nivel de los años 70

Comment: Nada impide que el usuario meta más caracteres que el límite establecido.

Comment: ¿Y si el usuario mete más caracteres que el nuevo tamaño del búfer grande que has establecido? Sigues con el mismo problema. Aparte, si vas leyendo carácter a carácter, ¿cómo sabes si el último carácter que introduce el usuario es sólo 1 carácter o mete muchos seguidos dejando basura en el búfer? Sigues con el mismo problema.

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez revisa la respuesta

Comment: Sí, esa sería una solución usando C estándar. Leyendo carácter a carácter te aseguras de saber si se introducen más o menos caracteres que el límite de la cadena, y por lo tanto limpiar el búfer en caso de haber introducido más. Lo que pasa que la pregunta iba más orientada a saber si existe alguna manera de limpiar el búfer de entrada sin saber si está lleno o no. Pero tu solución por ahora, es la mejor que me han proporcionado si nos limitamos a C estándar.

Comment: ¡Buen trabajo! Es muy buena solución. Voy a dejar un tiempo abierta la pregunta a ver si alguien por un casual conoce una manera de limpiar el búfer sin saber si está vacío o no (que era mi principal curiosidad). Si no aparece la respuesta terminaré confirmando la tuya como la buena.

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez opino como tú. el estándar tendría que ser mas flexible en este y en otros tantos aspectos

Comment: Sí, tienes toda la razón. Pero bueno. Investigar me ha servido para conocer las cosas que escribo en la respuesta, de las que no tenía ni idea (sobre todo los dos niveles de búfer). Parece como si el búfer de alto nivel fuese inaccesible directamente, salvo leyendo datos de él.

Comment: Voy a dejar la pregunta abierta de nuevo porque tu solución es válida cuando se leen cadenas de caracteres, pero si leo un entero con  `scanf()` no se puede saber si al introducir los datos está el búfer vacío o no para limpiarlo. Una solución sería leer la cadena y luego convertirla a entero manualmente, pero ya nos alejamos del objetivo inicial de la pregunta que era si existe alguna manera de saber si el búfer de entrada `stdin` está vacío. Lo siento :(

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez si lees un entero en el buffer habrá, al menos, un salto de línea ergo mi respuesta sigue siendo válida;)

Comment: Si por ejemplo introduces como entrada lo siguiente: `78   89`, al hacer `scanf("%d", &n)` en `n` se guarda el `78`, pero el resto de espacios y `89`, queda en el búfer. Si haces `scanf("%d ", &n)`  se guarda en `n` el `78` y limpias los espacios en blanco hasta el `89`, pero el `89` sigue quedando en el búfer. Ergo, no hay manera de saber si el usuario introdujo sólo `78` o algo más para ser limpiado o no.

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez eres tu el que como programador configura el `scanf` y desde ese momento eres tu el que tiene el control sobre lo que quieres leer. Si configuras mal la función no puedes echarle la culpa a otros

Comment: No, no tiene nada que ver con configurar mal el `scanf()`. Si esperas leer un entero, no puedes impedir que el usuario meta la entrada que le dé la gana.  Quizás te mete varios enteros separados por espacios. Por lo tanto, el primer entero lo lees bien, pero el resto queda en el búfer y te puede crear problemas en el resto del programa.

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez miralo así, si la entrada no es nada confiable lo qie tienes que hacer es leer de uno en uno y ante un fallo limpias el buffer y actuas en consecuencia. Nada de hacer lecturas raras... "%d" y a correr

Comment: Ya uso `%d` leyendo cada entero de uno en uno. Eso no soluciona la pregunta de saber si el búfer está o no vacío. Cuando ocurra un fallo, ¿cómo sabes si el búfer está vacío o no para limpiarlo?

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez si lees con "%d" salvo que redirecciones la entrada a un fichero siempre habrá algo en el buffer de entrada. La otra alternativa es leer linea a linea en un buffer interno y luego procesar ese buffer con sscanf o a mano

Comment: Sí, tienes toda la razón. Al hacer `scanf("%d", &n)` lee un entero pero el salto de línea posterior no lo toca, por lo tanto ya se lea un solo entero o un entero y más datos, siempre queda algo de datos en el búfer y por lo tanto el bucle `while` para lmpiarlo funcionará sin problemas. El problema surge si se hace un `scanf("%d ", &n)` que en este caso tras leer el número entero limpia el salto de línea posterior, y si se desea después limpiar el búfer entonces en ese caso sí se quedaría esperando. Es error mío. Genial, muchas gracias por ayudarme a entenderlo.Te vuelvo a validar la respuesta.

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez pero es como te digo... eso solo fallará si la stdin está leyendo de un fichero y has llegado al final del mismo... pero esa situación es bastante poco probable

Comment: No hace falta que se lea de un archivo para que haya problemas usando `scanf("%d ", &n)`. Si lees de teclado usando `scanf`  con espacio después del especificador `%d` en el formato, no hay manera de saber si el búfer está vacío o no una vez leídos los datos. En este caso, si se introduce un solo número estará vacío porque se limpia el salto de línea posterior al número,  pero si se introducen varios números separados por espacios no estará vacío, porque sólo lee el primer número y limpia los espacios en blanco hasta el segundo número. Al no leer más quedan datos en el resto en el búfer.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62512/discussion-between-eferion-and-carlos-a-gomez).

Answer (score 1):

Entre las posibles soluciones que he encontrado hasta ahora, todas están fuera del estándar de C:

- `fpurge` o `__fpurge` en glibc: funciona perfectamente pero, en el caso de Linux con `__fpurge`, pertenece a la librería estándar de GNU.
- `tcflush` de `termios.h`: está solución definida en POSIX es similar a `fpurge` pero, en lugar de limpiar el búfer del flujo a alto nivel `FILE *`, limpia el búfer a bajo nivel asociado con el descriptor de fichero (fd). Como el objetivo final es limpiar el búfer usando funciones como `scanf`, `fwrite`, `getchar`, etc, esta solución no valdría. Sólo valdría para el uso de funciones como `read` que manejan descriptores de fichero.
- `select` de `unistd.h`: está función definida en POSIX se puede usar para saber si el búfer asociado con un descriptor de fichero está vacío. Funciona perfectamente pero, como el caso de `tcflush`, sólo para búferes a bajo nivel asociados a descriptores de archivo. Implementé una función usando `select` para limpiar el búfer a bajo nivel asociado a un descriptor de fichero para entrada de datos y funciona perfectamente (al fin y al cabo hace lo mismo que `tcflush`), pero no afecta al búfer de alto nivel asociado con flujos de entrada `FILE *`.

  > ```
  > #include <unistd.h>
  > #include <stdlib.h>
  > #include <stdio.h>
  >
  > /*
  > * Limpiar el búfer de entrada a bajo nivel de un flujo de entrada.
  > *
  > * Argumentos:
  > * int fd: Descriptor de fichero a limpiar su búfer.
  > *
  > * Retorno:
  > * 0 si el búfer es limpiado correctamente.
  > * -1 si hay algún error.
  > */
  > int fflushin(int fd)
  > {
  >   struct timeval timeout, savetime;
  >   fd_set readfds, savefds;
  >   int retorno = 1;
  >   unsigned char byte;
  >
  >   timeout.tv_sec = 0;
  >   timeout.tv_usec = 0;    
  >   FD_ZERO(&readfds);
  >   FD_SET(fd, &readfds);
  >
  >   savefds = readfds;
  >   savetime = timeout;
  >
  >   do
  >   {
  >       int retselect = select(fd+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
  >
  >       switch (retselect)
  >       {
  >           case 0:
  >               retorno = 0;
  >               break;
  >           case -1:
  >               perror("Error en función select");
  >               retorno = -1;
  >               break;
  >           default:
  >               read(fd, &byte, 1);
  >               readfds = savefds;
  >               timeout = savetime;
  >               break;
  >       }
  >   } while (retorno == 1);
  >
  >   return retorno;
  > }
  > ```

Answer (score 0):

Si leímos los datos previamente con fgets se puede determinar si queda algo en el buffer de entrada STDIN. Esto es de la siguiente manera, veamos el siguiente código:

```
int len,i = 0;
char temporal[10];
printf("Ingrese una cadena: ");
fgets(temporal,10,stdin);
len = strlen(temporal);
printf("Cadena Leida: %s",temporal);
printf("La longitud de la cadena leida es de %i\n",len);
while(i<10) printf("%.2X",temporal[i++]);
printf("\n");
```

Si ya tenemos un poco de experiencia con fgets sabremos que si aun no alcanza el limite de caracteres, en este caso establecido en 10. Entonces en la cadena leída guardara el retorno de linea con valor 0xA. Veamos algunas cuantas salidas:

[image: Varias salidas del codigo antes mencionado]

Vemos que si nuestra variable tiene en su posición Strlen - 1 el valor 0xA significa que ya no hay nada por leer en el buffer.

En caso contrario, aun queda algo de datos en el buffer, ya sea el puro retorno de linea y/o texto adicional + el retorno de linea